# Static Route on Windows Mobile 5

Tags: ip, routing, windows-mobile

Does anyone know how to set up a static route on a windows mobile 5 device?

Answer (score 0):

There's an API call ([SetIpForwardEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450922.aspx)) to do it, so presumably it's possible. It doesn't sound like there are any built-in tools, however, to manipulate the routing table.

There was, apparently, a utility called [PocketCMD](http://digg.com/software/PocketCMD%3A_Command_Prompt_for_the_Pocket_Pc) that contained, amongst other useful utilities, a `route` command that [apparently worked](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/21869-36-manipulate-routing-table-windows-mobile-2003). The official download link for PocketCMD is dead now, but you may be able to locate it by Gooogling around for it.

Comment: I found the PocketCMD, but it didn't like Windows Mobile 5.  Thanks for the suggest tho...